# Adding table data to editable DataTables removes filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, html-table

I'm using an editable DataTable and when I add more than 4 table headers or table data it removes the filters of the table (Search, Sort, Pagination, Edit, etc).

This code works:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-none" id="datatable-editable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="gradeU">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>

      <td class="actions">
        <a href="#" class="hidden on-editing save-row"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="hidden on-editing cancel-row"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="on-default edit-row"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="on-default remove-row"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

result: 
[image: output 1]

This one doesn't:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-none" id="datatable-editable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="gradeU">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="actions">
        <a href="#" class="hidden on-editing save-row"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="hidden on-editing cancel-row"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="on-default edit-row"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="on-default remove-row"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

result:
[image: output 2]

And the only difference is the added header and table data
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Update:

I checked another DataTable that isn't editable but still has filters and i was able to successfully add table headers and table data.

The only difference between the tables are the dependent files:
example.datatables.default.js for the non-editable table and example.datatables.editable.js for the editable table

example.datatables.default.js

```
(function( $ ) {

'use strict';

var datatableInit = function() {

    $('#datatable-default').dataTable();

};

$(function() {
    datatableInit();
});
}).apply( this, [ jQuery ]);
```

example.datatables.editable.js

```
(function( $ ) {

'use strict';

var EditableTable = {

    options: {
        addButton: '#addToTable',
        table: '#datatable-editable',
        dialog: {
            wrapper: '#dialog',
            cancelButton: '#dialogCancel',
            confirmButton: '#dialogConfirm',
        }
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this
            .setVars()
            .build()
            .events();
    },

    setVars: function() {
        this.$table             = $( this.options.table );
        this.$addButton         = $( this.options.addButton );

        // dialog
        this.dialog             = {};
        this.dialog.$wrapper    = $( this.options.dialog.wrapper );
        this.dialog.$cancel     = $( this.options.dialog.cancelButton );
        this.dialog.$confirm    = $( this.options.dialog.confirmButton );

        return this;
    },

    build: function() {
        this.datatable = this.$table.DataTable({
            aoColumns: [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                { "bSortable": false }
            ]
        });

        window.dt = this.datatable;

        return this;
    },

    events: function() {
        var _self = this;

        this.$table
            .on('click', 'a.save-row', function( e ) {
                e.preventDefault();

                _self.rowSave( $(this).closest( 'tr' ) );
            })
            .on('click', 'a.cancel-row', function( e ) {
                e.preventDefault();

                _self.rowCancel( $(this).closest( 'tr' ) );
            })
            .on('click', 'a.edit-row', function( e ) {
                e.preventDefault();

                _self.rowEdit( $(this).closest( 'tr' ) );
            })
            .on( 'click', 'a.remove-row', function( e ) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var $row = $(this).closest( 'tr' );

                $.magnificPopup.open({
                    items: {
                        src: _self.options.dialog.wrapper,
                        type: 'inline'
                    },
                    preloader: false,
                    modal: true,
                    callbacks: {
                        change: function() {
                            _self.dialog.$confirm.on( 'click', function( e ) {
                                e.preventDefault();

                                _self.rowRemove( $row );
                                $.magnificPopup.close();
                            });
                        },
                        close: function() {
                            _self.dialog.$confirm.off( 'click' );
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

        this.$addButton.on( 'click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            _self.rowAdd();
        });

        this.dialog.$cancel.on( 'click', function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.magnificPopup.close();
        });

        return this;
    },

    // ==========================================================================================
    // ROW FUNCTIONS
    // ==========================================================================================
    rowAdd: function() {
        this.$addButton.attr({ 'disabled': 'disabled' });

        var actions,
            data,
            $row;

        actions = [
            '<a href="#" class="hidden on-editing save-row"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></a>',
            '<a href="#" class="hidden on-editing cancel-row"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>',
            '<a href="#" class="on-default edit-row"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>',
            '<a href="#" class="on-default remove-row"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>'
        ].join(' ');

        data = this.datatable.row.add(['', '', '', actions ]);
        $row = this.datatable.row( data[0] ).nodes().to$();

        $row
            .addClass( 'adding' )
            .find( 'td:last' )
            .addClass( 'actions' );

        this.rowEdit( $row );

        this.datatable.order([0,'asc']).draw(); // always show fields
    },

    rowCancel: function( $row ) {
        var _self = this,
            $actions,
            i,
            data;

        if ( $row.hasClass('adding') ) {
            this.rowRemove( $row );
        } else {

            data = this.datatable.row( $row.get(0) ).data();
            this.datatable.row( $row.get(0) ).data( data );

            $actions = $row.find('td.actions');
            if ( $actions.get(0) ) {
                this.rowSetActionsDefault( $row );
            }

            this.datatable.draw();
        }
    },

    rowEdit: function( $row ) {
        var _self = this,
            data;

        data = this.datatable.row( $row.get(0) ).data();

        $row.children( 'td' ).each(function( i ) {
            var $this = $( this );

            if ( $this.hasClass('actions') ) {
                _self.rowSetActionsEditing( $row );
            } else {
                $this.html( '<input type="text" class="form-control input-block" value="' + data[i] + '"/>' );
            }
        });
    },

    rowSave: function( $row ) {
        var _self     = this,
            $actions,
            values    = [];

        if ( $row.hasClass( 'adding' ) ) {
            this.$addButton.removeAttr( 'disabled' );
            $row.removeClass( 'adding' );
        }

        values = $row.find('td').map(function() {
            var $this = $(this);

            if ( $this.hasClass('actions') ) {
                _self.rowSetActionsDefault( $row );
                return _self.datatable.cell( this ).data();
            } else {
                return $.trim( $this.find('input').val() );
            }
        });

        this.datatable.row( $row.get(0) ).data( values );

        $actions = $row.find('td.actions');
        if ( $actions.get(0) ) {
            this.rowSetActionsDefault( $row );
        }

        this.datatable.draw();
    },

    rowRemove: function( $row ) {
        if ( $row.hasClass('adding') ) {
            this.$addButton.removeAttr( 'disabled' );
        }

        this.datatable.row( $row.get(0) ).remove().draw();
    },

    rowSetActionsEditing: function( $row ) {
        $row.find( '.on-editing' ).removeClass( 'hidden' );
        $row.find( '.on-default' ).addClass( 'hidden' );
    },

    rowSetActionsDefault: function( $row ) {
        $row.find( '.on-editing' ).addClass( 'hidden' );
        $row.find( '.on-default' ).removeClass( 'hidden' );
    }

};

$(function() {
    EditableTable.initialize();
});

}).apply( this, [ jQuery ]);
```

And JavaScript is definetly not my strong point.

Can someone please help me make sense of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is hard-coded for 4 columns. You need to change it so that any number of columns are accepted.

Change this line in `example.datatables.editable.js`:

```
this.datatable = this.$table.DataTable({
    aoColumns: [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        { "bSortable": false }
    ]
});
```

to:

```
this.datatable = this.$table.DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
        { targets: -1, orderable: false }
    ]
});
```

Also replace

```
data = this.datatable.row.add(['', '', '', actions ]);
```

with

```
var numCols = this.datatable.columns().nodes().length;
var rowData = [];
for(var i = 0; i < numCols - 1; i++){ rowData.push(''); }
rowData.push(actions);
data = this.datatable.row.add(rowData);
```

Comment: Hi @Gyrocode.com 
can you please help me. I have problem with datatables.editable.init.js
it loads with my main page (stops on breakpoint) but it does not get hit when I click on action in my table
'<a href="#" class="on-default edit-row"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>' or
'<a href="#" class="on-default remove-row"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>'